# Webpage hosted on openshift shows differently on mobile phone

Tags: openshift, openshift-php-cartidges

I've have built a countdown webpage using hmtl, css and some jquery and am hosting it on Openshift using a PHP cartridge. Checkout the webpage on http://www.hashworks.co

The server URL to the webpage is http://hashworksco-koble.rhcloud.com and I am redirecting the Cname to server URL and also using domain forwarding to redirect the naked domain to the same server.

In both the cases, i.e. whether the user types in 'www.hashworks.com' or just the 'hashwworks.com' the countdown webpage is displayed correctly on desktops but the view differs on mobile phones depending on the URL. In latter case on mobile phones I see a non responsive page which is same as what I see on desktops.

I am not able to figure out why this is happening and any help you can provide in troubleshooting this will be much appreciated. I have attached the screenshots for both scenarios.

Note: this issue is only seen on mobile phones. Also, this is my first time posting a query on stackoverflow so I don't have enough 'reputation' to quote more than two URLs or add screenshot images. Pardon me if the question has become ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "**but the view differs on mobile phones**" , What do you mean? : responsive, 404 error?

I tried your web in chrome and firefox and it works!! But when  I resize (ctrl + scroll bar ) the firefox and chrome , looks different, i.e responsive design.
the minutes and seconds are lost.

See screenshoots:

*before resize:
http://postimg.org/image/r30ai3odn/

*after resize:
http://postimg.org/image/n49fyetnz/

Resize the browser is almost the same that view on mobile phone.

Maybe is an error in your responsive functionality and is not error on openshift :s

Comment: Thanks JRichardsz for taking time and looking into my query and my apologies for replying so late, the issue was actually with the naked domain re-forwarding. It took me a bit of hit and trial but I was able to figure out the problem and fix it. I have written a post about this topic which others can find helpful. http://www.vkhanna.in/how-to-make-changes-to-domain-forwarding-settings/